# Can HP Intelligent Provisioning install RHEL using non-HP media?

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, hp-proliant

HP DL360p Gen8 has built in [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features) OS intallation. Will it work with stock RHEL bought on http://www.redhat.com or I have to buy Linux only from  [HP directly](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/operating-systems/product-detail.html?oid=5393115) ?

I don't want to buy Linux from HP because they sell it only with support, but I want to buy much cheaper self-support version.

**upd** I've bought 349$ RHEL 7 self-support and tried to install it ussing IP but in my case this doesn't work. I receive `Unable to find any valid media, add and choose "rescan"` error message.

**upd2** also found [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/279463) however not very helpful

**upd3** My guess is that RHEL7 still not supported in HP DL360p Gen8, but it supported in HP DL360p Gen9. Gen8 IP latest version is [Version 1.60 - February 18, 2014](https://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx=%7CswItem=MTX_bd68f366ac3748d6acb0892b7e%7CitemLocale=%7Cmode=%7Caction=driverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) and RHEL 7 is not supported in the description. Gen9 latest version is [Version 2.01 - September 9, 2014](https://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_c1951478bd594828b9fbbee076%257CswEnvOID%253D%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), and RHEL 7 is supported there

Comment: Call HP and ask them.  I'm not saying this to be flippant, they will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Gene I was calling our local Russia HP representative yesterday asking simple question "What is the correct way to buy self support RHEL for Proliant" and they answered me "I don't know, we more about hardware.". Probably I should try to submit a ticket because my server still has warranty.

Comment: Yeah, open a ticket or call their tech support line.  Sales/client reps don't usually know the finer details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use HP Intelligent Provisioning to install Linux on an HP server.

You can purchase [Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux) on your own, or just use [CentOS](https://www.centos.org), the free variant.

Comment: But I want to use Intelligent Provisioning because it makes things simple! for example "Ability to download drivers, firmware, and systems software by connecting directly to HP.com and to perform updates and install an OS in the same step"

Comment: You can use Intelligent Provisioning for firmware and other hardware preparation steps. You don't need it to install an OS, though.

Comment: i've used Intelligent Provisioning to install Windows and everything was very good, all HP tools were installed, I like this.

Comment: i've found that at least on my HP DL360p Gen8 it's easier to use regular OS installer, probably on Gen9 server IP is better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in general it should work.

According to [IP Gen8 Release notes](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04409569-1%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) latest version (1.61) of IP still doesn't support RHEL 7 by some reason. However, when I tried, IP recognized media and i'm able to install RedHat, but no HP tools were installed.

Happy owners of HP DL360p Gen9 must enjoy RHEL 7 installation via IP, because these servers contain newer 2.0 version of IP which supports RHEL 7 officially and so this probably will work better.

upd: It seems I should folow suggestion and use regular RedHat installer.

Comment: You don't need to use Intelligent Provisioning in order to install Linux. Please stop focusing on it. It's a very small portion of the process.